# Selector control is showing the wrong column values

Tags: acumatica

I created a selector control which displays a list of all serial #s from INItemLotSerial table, and it works fine. The problem is the description field is showing InventoryID, how to show InventoryCD. Here is my sample code:

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<INItemLotSerial.lotSerialNbr>),
    new Type[] { typeof(INItemLotSerial.lotSerialNbr), typeof(INItemLotSerial.inventoryID) },
    SubstituteKey = typeof(INItemLotSerial.lotSerialNbr), DescriptionField = typeof(INItemLotSerial.inventoryID))]
```

I also joined with InventoryItem but this doesn't work.

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search2<INItemLotSerial.lotSerialNbr,
        LeftJoinSingleTable<InventoryItem, On<InventoryItem.inventoryID,Equal<INItemLotSerial.inventoryID>>>>),
    new Type[] { typeof(INItemLotSerial.lotSerialNbr), typeof(INItemLotSerial.inventoryID) },
    SubstituteKey = typeof(INItemLotSerial.lotSerialNbr), DescriptionField = typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD))]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with `DescriptionField` property is that it is waiting for getting the field from the same table for which `Selector` is written. But in the case of ID/CD usually, the CD is not present in the table where ID is present, except the main table.

**UPDATED** I have removed previous code (implementation using custom attributes and FieldSelecting event handler) because of the performance issues which it is bringing with it. The code below is resulting with the same lookup but getting the data with one inner join instead of all the requests which the previous code was doing.

You can do the following to get this lookup with description:

1. Create a `PXProjection` on `INItemLotSerial` and `InventoryItem` tables like below:

   ```
   [PXCacheName("Lot Serials with Inventory CD")]
   [PXProjection(typeof(Select2<INItemLotSerial,
       InnerJoin<InventoryItem,
               On<INItemLotSerial.inventoryID, Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>>))]
   public class INItemLotSerialWithInventoryItem : IBqlTable
   {
       [PXDBInt(BqlField = typeof(INItemLotSerial.inventoryID))]
       [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Inventory ID", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible, Visible = false)]
       public virtual int? InventoryID { get; set; }

       public abstract class inventoryID : IBqlField { }

       [PXDBString(InputMask = "", IsUnicode = true, BqlField = typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD))]
       [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Inventory ID")]
       public virtual string InventoryCD { get; set; }
       public abstract class inventoryCD : IBqlField { }

       [PXDBString(InputMask = "", IsUnicode = true, BqlField = typeof(INItemLotSerial.lotSerialNbr))]
       [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Lot/Serial Nbr")]
       public virtual string LotSerialNbr { get; set; }
       public abstract class lotSerialNbr : IBqlField { }
   }
   ```
2. Set your selector to use this `PXProjection` like below:

   ```
   [PXSelector(typeof(Search<INItemLotSerialWithInventoryItem.lotSerialNbr>),
   new Type[] { typeof(INItemLotSerialWithInventoryItem.lotSerialNbr) }, 
       SubstituteKey = typeof(INItemLotSerialWithInventoryItem.lotSerialNbr), 
       DescriptionField = typeof(INItemLotSerialWithInventoryItem.inventoryCD))]
   ```

As a result, you will get lookup like below:
[image]

Comment: Could also try a PXProjection? Then use in the selector as this puts the lot serial and inventory table in the same DAC.

Comment: @Brendan yes, I didn't think about PXProjections. I think that will be a more acceptable solution as it will join the tables instead of selecting a record for each line.

Comment: Include that in your answer and see if John can get that working

Comment: Thank you very much Samvel and Brendan, will give a try and let you know guys.